# ping socket: Permission denied

Tags: networking, permissions

I am root.
ping 127.0.0.1 and return error;

```
root@sam-PC:~# ping 127.0.0.1 
socket: Permission denied

root@sam-PC:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:ff:ff:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.100.104  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::200:ffff:feff:0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2220 (2.2 KB)  TX bytes:524 (524.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3160 (3.1 KB)  TX bytes:3160 (3.1 KB)



root@sam-PC:~# ping 192.168.100.100
socket: Permission denied
```

who knows why?

Comment: Please describe your system with many more details. Is it Ubuntu or another linux distro? (Otherwise we can only guess. The ping command works on my computer both as a regular user and via sudo.)

Comment: Are you using the Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: This is a armhf ubuntu 14.04. Other devices can ping this device,and it's ok. ubuntu rootfs is from this command "sudo qemu-debootstrap --arch armhf  trusty /rootfs/"

Comment: I has solved this problem. this is a kernel config question CONFIG_ANDROID_PARANOID_NETWORK .add this inet:x:3003:root
net_raw:x:3004:root

Answer (score 3):

For this problem, we should add the following lines to `/etc/group`:

```
inet:x:3003:root
net_raw:x:3004:root
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain why this should work, and what it does? It didn't solve the issue for me..

Answer (score 0):

The underlying ping is using sock_raw. To create such a socket, you must have 
    root privileges.

```
int main(void) {
    rawsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, protocol->p_proto);
    if(rawsock < 0){
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

If the owner of the ping is not root, the error will not be fixed.
    Using the linux capability mechanism can't solve the problem.

Comment: I was skeptical but, even when run as root, I see ping's initial SOCK_DGRAM socket creation failing, so indeed SOCK_RAW ends up being used:
```socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 3```

Answer (score 0):

The OP is executing ping as root, so this isn't an answer to them, more an extended comment on the answer from @leesagacious.  In my situation, on CentOS Stream 8, so doubly inappropriate for askubuntu... unless it happens there too, the Linux capability mechanism does appear to the the answer, kudos https://superuser.com/a/1616749/17633:

```
[manager@smu-centos8-daily-test ~]$ ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
ping: socket: Operation not permitted
[manager@smu-centos8-daily-test ~]$ getcap /usr/bin/ping
[manager@smu-centos8-daily-test ~]$ sudo setcap cap_net_raw+p /usr/bin/ping
[manager@smu-centos8-daily-test ~]$ ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=4.57 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.567/4.567/4.567/0.000 ms
[manager@smu-centos8-daily-test ~]$ getcap /usr/bin/ping
/usr/bin/ping = cap_net_raw+p
[manager@smu-centos8-daily-test ~]$ sudo setcap -r /usr/bin/ping
[manager@smu-centos8-daily-test ~]$ getcap /usr/bin/ping
[manager@smu-centos8-daily-test ~]$ ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
ping: socket: Operation not permitted
[manager@smu-centos8-daily-test ~]$
```

I don't think that the *owner* of ping, as opposed to the uid of the process executing ping, would be relevant, except back in the days when ping was setuid.